# Passing data to forecast.lm using dplyr and do

Tags: r, dplyr, lm, forecasting

I am having trouble passing data to `forecast.lm` in a `dplyr do`. I want to make several models based on a a factor - `hour` - and the forecaste these models using new data.

Building on previous excellent examples here is my data example:

```
require(dplyr)
require(forecast)

# Training set
df.h <- data.frame( 
  hour     = factor(rep(1:24, each = 100)),
  price    = runif(2400, min = -10, max = 125),
  wind     = runif(2400, min = 0, max = 2500),
  temp     = runif(2400, min = - 10, max = 25)  
)

# Forecasting set
df.f <- data.frame(
  hour     = factor(rep(1:24, each = 10)),
  wind     = runif(240, min = 0, max = 2500),
  temp     = runif(240, min = - 10, max = 25)  
)

# Bind training & forecasting
df <- rbind(df.h, data.frame(df.f, price=NA))

# Do a training model and then forecast using the new data
df <- rbind(df.h, data.frame(df.f, price=NA))
res <- group_by(df, hour) %>% do({
  hist <- .[!is.na(.$price), ]
  fore <- .[is.na(.$price), c('hour', 'wind', 'temp')]
  fit <- Arima(hist$price, xreg = hist[,3:4], order = c(1,1,0))
  data.frame(fore[], price=forecast.Arima(fit, xreg = fore[ ,2:3])$mean)
})
res
```

This works excellently with a time series model, but using a `lm` I have problem passing the data into the forecasting part.

My corresponding `lm` example looks like this:

```
res <- group_by(df, hour) %>% do({
  hist <- .[!is.na(.$price), ]
  fore <- .[is.na(.$price), c('hour', 'wind', 'temp')]
  fit <- lm(hist$price ~ wind + temp, data = hist)
  data.frame(fore[], price = forecast.lm(fit, newdata = fore[, 2:3])$mean)
})
```

The problem is that I cant' get data into the `newdata =` function. If you add `hist$` in the fit section, you can't reference the forecast data, and for some reason if you add `data = fore` it can't find it - but it can in the time series example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `forecast.lm` expects that `fit` has a `data` component. If you use `glm` or `tslm`, that is true. But `lm` objects don't generally have a `data` component. So you need to manually add `fit$data <- hist` for `forecast.lm` to work properly.

```
res <- group_by(df, hour) %>% do({
  hist <- .[!is.na(.$price), ]
  fore <- .[is.na(.$price), c('hour', 'wind', 'temp')]
  fit <- lm(price ~ wind + temp, data = hist)
  fit$data <- hist # have to add data manually
  data.frame(fore[], price = forecast.lm(fit, newdata = fore[, 2:3])$mean) 
})
```

This is actually a [known issue](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/113).